# Character limit while importing headers from excel using SSIS

Tags: excel, vb.net, ssis, integration, connection-string

I am trying to import headers from Excel document that I want to put in an array string.

However, I noticed that there is a character limit of 64 characters. This means that some of my headers are being truncated. This is the connection I am using:

```
Dim connectionstr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
```

Is there something I am doing or an alternative method?

Comment: 64 chars is a hard-coded limit imposed by the engine. You have specified `Excel 8.0` (so, a `.xls` file).

Comment: Is there alternative engine that I can use?

Comment: [NPOI - GitHub](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi). If your file is actually a Office '97 format. Otherwise [EPPlus - GitHub](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)